# Where should I put the empty base class?

Tags: c++, optimization, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Does the order in which I list the base classes matter when one of them is empty and the other one is not?

```
class Foo : normal_class, empty_class { ... };

class Foo : empty_class, normal_class { ... };
```

Does the order affect the compiler's ability to apply the empty base class optimization?

Comment: I don't have the standard at hand at the moment (would not be a comment), but from the top off my hat I'd say that Standard does not restrict the optimization to a specific position in the base list.

Comment: Is it feasible to make a real-world test and compare the assembly?

Comment: LOL, I tried answering a similar question a couple years ago by making a real-world test. I screwed up the experiment, got the wrong result, and got my ass handed to me.

Comment: … hah! Screwed up my answer again. Forgot the rules and didn't read carefully. Maybe the third time will be a charm.

Comment: Why assembly? Can't you just check the sizeof the resulting Foo?

Comment: Does `empty_class` contain any methods/constructors ? If it's completely empty then I am interested to know what is your purpose of inheriting.

Comment: @iam: [Barton Nackman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it matters - although I tend to try to put an empty base first anyway.

There's an interesting note on multiple empty bases on the boost site: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#old_lib_note

Answer (score 0):

It's irrelevant -- after some data members are inherited, the compiler may pad the class arbitrarily. So no, the empty optimisation is not neccessarily applied.